# What is the .NET equivalent to Nexus and/or what is its use regharding deploying .net core apps?

Tags: asp.net, maven, asp.net-core, nexus

I am a .NET dev told to start using Nexus to help IT deploy .net core web apps. So I have tried to figure out what nexus is. From what I understand I would use it if I was to create custom NuGet packages and want them hosted behind the firewall?.. But what does that have to do with deploying .net core web apps ?

I feel like I totally am not getting it and the articles about Nexus/Maven make no sense to me .. Maybe it is because I come from the pure .NET world..

The original request is below... Can someone explain to me in a language I can understand what they are talking about  ? Why can't I just send them docker images??

> In our EA meeting today the SA team mentioned that they were pulling code out of nexus to build their docker containers. Did you want to do some research on Nexus to see if we can use it the same way? I know that it's possible to use Nexus to host your own nuget repo's but I've got nothing much beyond that.
>
> If you could summarize your findings in this ticket I think that'll be
>   a good starting point and we can take it from there.

Comment: Nexus is like a private version of Nuget Gallery you host yourself.  You can proxy nuget.org to pull public stuff and publish your own private packages.  You can then bundle up those private packages into docker containers to deploy.

Comment: Ok. But I have no need to create my own nugget packages. I am simply creating a .net core website that uses some 3rd party nugget packages. So I guess this is not for me. Maybe the java side of the team has some other way to approach it I don't get

Comment: Do you mean like a common DLL that is used by many other programmers on the .net team? So it is an alternative to directly using the DLL or something ? I am trying to understand the advantage

Comment: It keeps a versioned history of builds and releases.  The idea is you publish packages as you go.  Then you select one for deployment. For example, your testing team can grab one, test it, and approve it.  Then that same package can be deployed.  It may be overkill for a simple one-person dev team, but you may want to rethink your process if you want repeatability and auditability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create an app, you can use many packages. Nuget packages, bower packages, and so on. For example, this piece of a project.json is telling "get all this packages from the repository":

```
  //...
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "NHibernate": "4.0.4.4000",
    "System.Data.Common": "4.1.0"
  //...
```

When using Nuget packages, we usually get them from the [official repository](https://www.nuget.org/). But you can create a local repository at your company. This way, you can store the packages from your company in this private repository. Or, if the developers can't access the internet, someone can download the package and upload it into the local server. You can also use both servers (private and public) to get some common packages and the packages your company created.

This way, if you're gonna use Nexus, then you can create a Nuget (or other kind of packages: Docker, bower, maven) package and upload it to your Nexus server. Then, you configure your project to look for the packages in the Nexus server instead of looking for it in the public repository. Or, like I said before, you can use both private and public.

The piece of text you quoted is telling the SA team is using Nexus as their repository. And they're probably using Nexus to store their Docker packages, and maybe their Nuget packages too. So, their projects are downloading the packages from the Nexus server.

Comment: I don't see a point of hosting any nugget packages here.. But what do they mean about docker?  Send them docker images ?

Comment: It's nice if you want to have private packages, for example. They may have docker pckages in a private repository.

Answer (score 0):

So for Nexus Repository Manager what I'd expect to see reading that, is that you'd be creating NuGet packages for your .NET code, and deploying those to NuGet hosted repositories in the Repository Manager. From there, these packages could be obtained either by a Dockerfile (if you were using NuGet within it to get packages, or potentially via curl, etc...) and then a Docker image could be created of your application and shared to a Docker hosted repository in Repository Manager. It is completely possible to use Nexus Repository to host Docker images, and I strongly suggest you do so (we built it, after all :) ).

Comment: The point I don't understand is what exactly are these nugget packages?  Are these for example a utility .net DLL that I create as a nugget package instead of a compiled DLL ?  Or maybe I should say 'deploy' as a nugget package instead of a DLL that is packaged up with my app ?

Comment: I would think of a NuGet package in terms of any packaged up amount of functionality. In many ways it is the same as a compiled DLL, but it could be a collection of quite a few that are either an application, or a library of functionality you want to share. This could be one DLL or many, as a result. Maybe take a read over here for some more familiarity with it: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingNuGetPackageManagementForNETAnotherPieceOfTheWebStack.aspx

Comment: So the important piece to realize is that my 'web site' could be a nugget package then right?  I think my problem is I hear nugget and think of it in the traditional way I use nugget which is just a bunch pointers to some 3rd party DLLs

Comment: Anything can be abused, obviously. I think the example of Elmah is a great thought on what a NuGet package SHOULD be. It can also be your website, or application, etc... if it needs to be.